# PHP create empty object using existing object of same class

Tags: php

Is there are any native PHP function equivalent of the following:

```
function newObject($object) {
    $class = get_class($object);
    return new $class;
}
```

Comment: [Well, what do you know?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) *(first result for `get name of class object belongs to`)*

Comment: @DJDavid98 not quite. That returns name of class, not actual object. Said function is used in the example

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't notice you needed a native function. That said, I doubt there is one.

Comment: @RyanVincent He's asking if there's a built-in function to do exactly what he's doing here I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is.

And there is no shortcut either. `new get_class($x);` tries to use the class `get_class`, and `new (get_class($x));` is syntactically incorrect, because the parentheses are not allowed. You can use a variable containing a class name, but you cannot use any string expression.

Comment: I agree. You *could* take a "shortcut" by making a function such as `function makeInstance($str){ return new $str; }` and calling it like `return makeInstance(get_class($x))`, but that might just count as taking the longer route. @OP should stick to their implementation, as a function just for this purpose seems like an unlikely addition to the language,

Answer (score 1):

Single function, no. Idiomatic way, yes. Use [`ReflectionObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php):

```
class Foo {
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = 'baz';

// this is the magic:
$new = (new ReflectionObject($foo))->newInstance();

var_dump($foo, $new);
```

[See it live](https://3v4l.org/bb51A).